# How to take all of the redis zset data above a score with less memory?

Tags: php, concurrency, redis

> ENV: PHP7/redis 3.0

I use `redis zset` to save a orderly list. When it reaches a certain point in time, I need to save the state at this time. And the question is, some data should be saved that is score gt a number, if a score is above this number, I must get it and save to other `zset` use other key. It will too much data. So I want to use `php generators`, but if this time a member's score changed, it can be **missed**.

So, How to resolve it?

Comment: use lua script, or atomically remove data from the set and save to other set using multi and execute commands.